# Woocommerce API Lookup Customer Details based off Email

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to look up a customer's details by referencing their email address using the Woocommerce API.

```
https://example.com/wc-api/v3/customers/?consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxx
```

Is there a way I can get the customer's details through an email parameter instead of ID? I can't seem to find anything in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good. Figured it out. It was this API address:

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?email=xxx&consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxxx`